# Compiler optimization for loops

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-construction

I have frequently noticed the following pattern:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
  // do some operations on string
}
```

The complexity of above loop would be `O(N²)` because the complexity of `strlen` is `N` and that comparison is made during every iteration.

However, if we calculate `strlen` before the loop and use that constant, the complexity of the loop is reduced to `O(N)`.

I am sure there are many other such optimizations.

Does the compiler carry out such optimizations or do programmers have to take precautions to prevent it?

Comment: I assume reduced to `O(N)`?

Comment: This optimization happens sometimes, with some compilers, but not always. Relying on it would be a horrible idea. You don't want to debug the resulting weird performance degradation when you switch compilers or some change prevents the optimization from happening.

Comment: First: what is __N__ in this context? Number of.. what? (So, why are you multiplying number of two different things). Next, what is __str__ in this context? What is the string? For null-terminated strings it will be needed to go to it's end to recognize length, but there are also other ways to store string. For example, store string length at it's beginning (thus, "strlen" will have constant time)

Comment: @TejasPatel your assumption [is wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Length-prefixed) (I hate to reference on wikipedia, but the clue is at least described there). There are different ways to store strings. Either your current question isn't complete or you need to specify which kind of strings are you using.

Comment: @TejasPatel Java stores the length of string. Since strings are immutable this is possible and feasible.

Comment: @AlmaDo: the OP writing "the complexity of strlen is O(N)" is enough to make us understand that he refers to C-style null terminated strings, N characters long.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The OP wasn't aware that there are implementation storing the string length. Therefore OP assumed that `strlen` must be `O(n)`. Which in fact is not always true. The question itself does not state a programming language nor a compiler. I would be very surprised if the JIT compiler does not optimize this code snippet.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind: Allow me not to believe that there exist implementations of C strings that keep a length field: any write to the array of chars would require to update the length, a worst-case O(N) operation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust [ustr](http://www.and.org/ustr/) does this for example. Take also a look at these [string implementations](http://www.and.org/vstr/comparison)

Comment: A better optimization is to avoid the length pre-calculation: `for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; ++i)`

Comment: @Absurd-Mind: I don't think you get my point about the efficiency of modifying the string.

Comment: @Ferruccio, I think the question is specifically about whether the compiler will perform such an optimisation _itself_.

Comment: @davmac - I agree. That's why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is: Never leave a run-time complexity optimization to the compiler. If a compiler screws up a micro-optimization, your code slows down by a constant factor. If it screws up here, you go from `O(N)` to `O(N^2)`.

Comment: [Click here to submit feedback about your question-asking experience.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have any solid evidence whatsoever, my guess would be this:

The compiler makes a data flow analysis of the variable `str`. If it's potentially modified inside the loop or marked as `volatile`, there is no guarantee that `strlen(str)` will remain constant between iterations and therefore cannot be cached. Otherwise, it should be safe to cache and would be optimized.

Comment: Your unstated assumption is that the compiler knows `strlen` is a pure function. Not the most far-fetched assumption, but worth noting.

Comment: Both `str` **and** the characters between the one pointed by `str` and the first `'\0'` that follows must remain unchanged for the compiler to be easily able to infer that `strlen(str)` remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, good optimizers are able to do this kind of transform if they can establish that the string remains unmodified in the loop body. They can pull out of loops expressions that remain constant.

Anyway, in a case where you would, say, turn all characters to uppercase, it would be hard for a compiler to infer that the string length won't change.

I personally favor a "defensive" approach, not relying on advanced compiler skills, and do the obvious optimizations myself. In case the code would be ported to a different environment, with a poorer compiler, or just in case of doubt.

Also think of the cases where optimization is off.

Comment: The case you gave is a most interesting one, as one can easily forget - or ignore - that the unoptimized version is O(N²).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i) {
   // do some operations on string 
 }
```

As `strlen` is essentially doing this

Comment: It seems OP is aware such optimization is possible. He is asking if the compiler will do it with the original code, which may seem to carry the intent better. Seasoned C developer would probably avoid using i at all and would do something like for (const char *c=str; *c; ++c) ...

Comment: @Suma - It avoids running through the loop twice. But your solution assumes that the value is not required in the code in the for loop. Perhaps if we knew what that is then there will be some other solutions

Answer (score 0):

The first step towards understanding what compilers do, can do, and can not do is to write your intentions into the code and see what happens:

```
const int len = strlen(str);
for (int i=0; i<len; ++I)
{
  // do some operations which DO NOT CHANGE the length of str
}
```

Of course, it is your responsibility not to change the length of str inside the loop...you can lowercase, uppercase, swap or replace characters...something you may 'assert()' if you really care (in a debug version). In this case, you communicated your intentions to the compiler and if you are lucky and you are using a good compiler you are likely to get what you are after.

I really doubt that this optimisation would make any difference in your code: if you were doing heavy string manipulation you would (1) know whether you are working with long strings or short ones, (2) be using a library which (a) keeps explicit track of the length of strings, (b) makes (especially repeated) string concatenation cheaper as it is in C.